# How do I send headers and data to a web socket in Ruby/Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, header, ruby-on-rails-5

With Ruby on Rails 5, how do I send headers to a web socket in addition to the data?  I found this gem

```
https://github.com/shokai/websocket-client-simple
```

that allows one to send data using

```
ws.send 'hello!!!'
```

after establishing the connection, but I don't see anywhere in this library where you can specify additional headers when connecting to the web socket as a client.  How can one achieve this?  I'm not tied to using this particular gem so if there's another that allows one to send headers AND data to a web socket that would satisfy my requirement.

Comment: What's wrong with good old-fashioned `Net::HTTP`? Assuming you need the HTTP protocol...

Comment: The Net::HTTP set up seems to be more stateless -- you send a request, wait for a response.  Web sockets seem to allow for asynchronous handling of events.  If Net::HTTP can do the same thing as web sockets, could you post an example?